# Authorization code exchange doesn't work with Google OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm implementing google sign-in on backend according to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).

I have a JS client:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>

function start() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
             client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
             scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
        });
    });
}

<button id="signinButton">Login Google</button>
<script>
    $('#signinButton').click(function() {
        auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(signInCallback);
    });
</script>
```

And in `signInCallback` function I'm sending `authResult['code']` to the server.

On the server I need to generate `id_token` and `access_token` from `serverAuthCode`. My backend is written in ASP.NET CORE.

The tutorial has backend implementation examples for Java and Python. On the server I'm doing the following:

```
var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", serverAuthCode),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "MY_CLIENT_ID"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "MY_REDIRECT_URI_DEFINED_IN_GOOGLE_CONSOLE")
});
var tokenResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", data);
```

And I'm always getting bad request with one of the errors (randomly):

- redirect_uri_mismatch
- invalid_grant

Am I doing something wrong with the request?

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same URL? See [redirect_uri](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) under "gapi.auth2.ClientConfig"

Comment: I can't say I know much about this area, but you might want to look at the code in https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc/OAuth2/Mvc - that's not for ASP.NET Core, but should show what you'd need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks exactly like the method I use successfully with an other OAuth2
/OIDC provider. The only exception is an `Accept` header, so can you add this to your code (not sure if it will fix your random behavior but it might be worth to try).

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

For completeness, this is the method I'm using:

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> ExchangeCodeForTokens(Uri tokenEndpoint, string code, Uri redirectUri, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
        {"code", code},
        {"redirect_uri", redirectUri.ToString()},
        {"client_id", clientId},
        {"client_secret", clientSecret}
    });

    using (var client = _httpClientFactory())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new OpenIdConnectException($"Request to token endpoint {tokenEndpoint} not successful: {responseContent}");

        var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseContent);
        if (tokenResponse == null)
            throw new OpenIdConnectException($"Request to token endpoint {tokenEndpoint} did not return a valid response: {responseContent}");

        return tokenResponse;
    }
}
```

Where `TokenResponse` is:

```
public class TokenResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresInSeconds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TimeSpan ExpiresIn => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ExpiresInSeconds);
}
```